# Java. Swing. Make setDefaultCloseOperation close the current frame but also open another frame when the X button is clicked in the top right

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class B extends JFrame {

    B(){
        this.setSize(1000,1000);
        this.setVisible(true);
        A a = new A();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(a.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Okay, I have two frames: Frame A and Frame B. When the program executes Frame A opens. When a button is pressed in Frame A, Frame A is hidden and Frame B opens. I need to dispose Frame B, and make Frame A visible again when the default X button is pressed in Frame B. I'm using Swing and I can't figure it out. If there's already a solution on stack, I couldn't find it, but would appreciate a link. Thank you.

Also I would prefer not creating a brand new instance of a frame that is already open. How could I make Frame A visible again. I know it would be easy to make a button for this but I need it for the default X button.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) *"I know it would be easy to make a button for this but I need it for the default X button."* ... ***Why?*** 4) See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: .. 5) `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(a.setVisible(true));` Does that actually compile? `setVisible` returns nothing (`void`), while the other method requires an `int` based argument.

Comment: No it was just to demonstrate what I was aiming for. I see how that could be misleading

Comment: *"just to demonstrate what I was aiming for"* Posting uncompilable code is not a good demonstration for anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about adding a listener?

```
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { 
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { 
                a.setVisible(true)
        }
    });
```

Comment: `setVisible(false); dispose();` Not needed. Just use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Done, my friend.